# Is there a shortcut for inserting PHP's object operator upon code completion in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Let's say I want to type the following in PhpStorm:

```
$longObjectName->propertyName = 'some value';
```

Seems innocent enough, no? If I start typing `longOb`, code completion kicks in and helpfully provides `$longObjectName` as a suggestion, since it exists elsewhere in my project. I think to myself, "Ah perfect, that's exactly what I wanted", so I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to accept the suggestion. At this point, I'm feeling pretty happy.

But now I want to insert `->`, PHP's awkward but familiar object operator. If I type it manually, that's **three whole keystrokes** (including <kbd>Shift</kbd>), which makes me feel just a bit sad. A distant, nagging doubt begins to enter my mind. "*Three* keystrokes? What kind of evil IDE is this? Who are these ruthless dictators at JetBrains??"

The emotional roller coaster continues when I see the following in PhpStorm's Tip of the Day dialog, bringing a minuscule but insistent glimmer of hope to my dark, Monokai-schemed world:

> When using Code Completion, you can accept the currently highlighted
>   selection in the popup list with the period character (`.`), comma (`,`),
>   semicolon (`;`), space and other characters.
>
> The selected name is
>   automatically entered in the editor followed by the entered character.

In JavaScript, this means I can type `longOb` and hit <kbd>.</kbd> to both accept the first code completion suggestion and insert the JS object operator, resulting in `longObjectName.`, at which point I can keep typing a property name and go on autocompleting all day long without ever hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Amazing. Revolutionary even.

Now for some devastating news: it doesn't seem to work in PHP. (Fret not children—this harrowing tale is almost at its end.)

If I type `longOb` and then hit <kbd>-</kbd>, I get this:

```
longOb-      // :(
```

I'm pretty sure the PHP interpreter wouldn't like me very much if I tried to execute that.

(Side note: <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>, and <kbd>;</kbd> exhibit pretty much the same behavior, contrary to the quoted Tip of the Day above.)

So here's what I would get if I were to make my fantasy world a reality:

```
$longObjectName->[handy dandy code completion list, primed and ready for action]
```

Wouldn't that be *flipping awesome*?

So finally, we arrive at the ultimate question, with some redundant stuff added for those who didn't bother to read my action-packed, heartwrenching story:

**Is there a single keyboard shortcut in PhpStorm for "Accept the currently highlighted code completion suggestion and insert the PHP object operator (`->`)"?**

Or is this just a bug?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, I solved this problem by recording a Macro and then binding it with a keyboard shortcut:

1. Go to Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording
2. Type '->'
3. Stop Macro Recording using the button in the lower right corner, then name it whatever you want.
4. Assign Shortcut to it:

   - Go to File | Settings | Keymap | Macros |
   - Right click  and choose 'Add Keyboard Shortcut'

I chose Ctrl+. as the shortcut and now I am more than happy. :)

Comment: Ah of course! Why didn't I think of creating a macro? I've changed my accepted answer to yours. (Daniel's AutoHotkey idea is interesting too, but  not cross-platform.)

Comment: Cool answer.Help save so much time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use autohotkey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create new keystrokes and replace PHP Object Operator for period or anything else.

For example, with a script like this:

```
^.::
Send ->
return
```

Will replace (ctrl + .) with (->), in anywhere in Windows.

Or

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class SunAwtFrame
.::
Send ->
return
```

Will replace . (period) with (->) only in PhpStorm Window (Or others with ahk_class SunAwtFrame).
Use Window Spy to see the ahk_class class of any Windows Window.

You can use CTRL + . as . (period)

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class SunAwtFrame
^.::
Send .
return
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** As far as I remember this kind of completion was asked to be removed for PHP code (too unusual) .. but I cannot find such ticket right now (already spend over 20 mins on this) .. so I could be wrong (*it was quite some time ago .. so possibly I'm confused with another code-completion improvement which was hard-configured to behave differently for PHP code only*).

Kind of related to "why it was disabled/what problems where there in the past":

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7013
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88179
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59718

**In any case:** there is an open ticket to actually having it working: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21481 (only 1 vote so far).

**2)** There is no "complete with ->" action available. Related ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17658 (star/vote/comment to get notified on progress)