# Does anybody know how to add hook for php storm for changing . to ->?

Tags: php, hook, phpstorm

Very hard adding all time -> into php code.
Maybe does anybody knows how to optimize it process? =)

What I mean:

```
$somevar. /*automatic changes to*/ $somevar->
```

P.S.: *I heard that into netBeans or maybe another IDE have this hook by default.*

Comment: Don't understand what you are trying to do, even `$somevar=>` isn't valid PHP. Please clarify. If you want to simple Replace something, press`CTRL+SHIFT+R`

Comment: Sorry! I did a typo into the question =)

Comment: If I understand correct, you want to copy some Code from another language `foo.Bar.Baz()` into PHPStorm and convert it on the fly to the PHP equivalent `$foo->bar->baz()`? If not please clarify a bit more.

Comment: Ah now I understand... Possible Dub? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22513914/2441442