# Shortcut/feature for prepending $this automatically in Intellij/Phpstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is it possible/does such feature exist that when I write an instance variable name (without $this->) it would search for a declared variable? I think it would save a bit of time not writing $this-> anytime I need to access an instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently such functionality is not available in PhpStorm.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-19345 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

Right now I may only suggest to write custom **Live Template** that would convert `t[TAB]` (or whatever abbreviation you desire) to `$this->` with code completion popup already shown.

Related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-551

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is save yourself the trouble of writing `$this->`, join the club. :) Macros are here for rescue.

I solved this problem by recording a Macro and then binding it with a keyboard shortcut:

1. Go to Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording
2. Type '$this->'
3. Stop Macro Recording using the button in the lower right corner, then name it whatever you want.
4. Assign Shortcut to it:

   - Go to File | Settings | Keymap | Macros
   - Right click and choose 'Add Keyboard Shortcut'

I chose `Ctrl+.` as the shortcut and now I am more than happy. :)

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27345479/4178110)